# set value to form control on Init not working angular2

Tags: angular

I have following code to add control in OnInit method.

```
    this.form = new FormGroup({});
    this.form.addControl('select', new FormControl(''));
```

after adding the control i am not able set the value to control;

```
    this.form.controls['select'].SetValue()
```

but its throwing exception as select as undefined

Comment: Have you tried initializing the `FormGroup` in your class constructor? Not sure exactly what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the same by using `get` method of `formGroup` :

```
this.form.get('select').setValue('');
```